# React Native - How to measure size of content in ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollview, react-native, nativemethodsmixin

I want to measure the size of the content in my `ScrollView`.

Therefore, I am using `measure` from `NativeMethodsMixin`:

```
import NativeMethodsMixin from 'NativeMethodsMixin'
```

I am not quite sure where to go from here, most SO posts relating to this issue seem to be outdated.

I understand that I need to create a `ref` to my `ScrollView` (which I did and called `_scrollView`, I can access it using `this.refs._scrollView`).

Problem is, I can't just pass in `this.refs._scrollView` into `measure` like so:

```
NativeMethodsMixin.measure(this.refs._scrollView, (data) => {
  console.log('measure: ', data)
})
```

I am getting the following error then:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:61 findNodeHandle(...): Argument is not a component (type: object, keys: measure,measureInWindow,measureLayout,setNativeProps,focus,blur,componentWillMount,componentWillReceiveProps)
```

I then tried to retrieve the actual node handle using `findNodeHandle` and pass it into `measure` as discussed in this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1060):

```
const handle = React.findNodeHandle(this.refs._scrollView)
NativeMethodsMixin.measure(handle, (data) => {
  console.log('measure: ', data)
})
```

But this results in the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NativeMethodsMixin.measure.call(elementToMeasure, (x, y, width, height) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Please add a source for `NativeMethodsMixin`

Answer (score 26):

ScrollView defines a prop called [onContentSizeChange](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange):

```
<ScrollView
  onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => {
    console.log(width, height);
  }}>
  {content}
</ScrollView>
```