# How to scroll to initial index with SectionList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Problem: I have a section list of dates and I want to scroll to the middle of it when the list is first displayed (which will be the current date)

To use `scrollToLocation` you have to implement `getItemLayout`, which I have done.  Using `scrollToLocation` works well enough after the initial list is visible, and the user wants to navigate to any section (date).

However, the initial `scollToLocation` fails because it seems to execute before the list has fully rendered.  There is a timing issue.

If I issue `scrollToLocation` after a time delay, it kind of works, but of course that is problematic, and mostly an antipattern.  There is always the risk with a slow device that the delay is not long enough, and if I make the delay very long, then faster devices will be waiting for no reason, and it also starts to look odd - the longer delay makes the list visibly jump around.

The timing issue is also exasperated because I don't have the height of the list elements hard-coded because they can be variable - I wait until a measurement is performed by `onLayout` of an item, then that gets fed back into `getItemLayout`.

This works well - no matter what height the items turn out to be, the list navigates fine -- except the initial use of `scrollToLocation` as I mentioned above

I have tried tying the **scrollToLocation** call as an effect dependent on both the section I want to scroll to, and the itemHeight  with **useEffect**  The thinking here is that useEffect is only called after a render and in this case only triggers once the itemHeight has been set by onLayout.  But still the call to scrollToLocation is too soon and does not work.  It seems to scroll to a random location.

SUMMARY:  I need a way to reliably trigger the initial scrollToLocation call after the list has completely finished the initial render, so that the call actually works.  One that doesnt involve arbitrary time delays.  If not useEffect, what can I do?

cheers

Comment: have you tried
 
 scrollToLocation(
        {
          sectionIndex: sectionIndex,
          itemIndex: itemIndex
        }
      )

Comment: yes mate, the issue is not what fucntion to use, but how to time the call so that reliably happens immediately after the list has rendered.  Calling it before then seems to have no effect,m and triggering the scrollToLocation via useEffect doesnt help either

Comment: by using list ref you can able to get the length, if I has then trigger the function

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720879/react-native-how-to-measure-size-of-content-in-scrollview